# Screen reader is not reading options of the custom drop-down

Tags: html, screen-readers, nvda

I have a custom js dropdown, which is not read by screen readers, If dropdown is open, moving from one option to another using arrow keys won't be read, only after selecting one of the options the selected options is pronounced, so the problem is, users won't have any idea about the list of available options until they select one.

I have defined the role but it is still not working.

```
<div class="select__holder" role="listbox" id="select-7181726" style="top: 1540px; max-height: 324.955px; left: 531.352px; width: 759px;">
    <div id="select-7181726option-11" data-index="0" data-value="1" role="option" class="select__option" aria-selected="false">
        <span class="select__option__lbl">  
            <span class="select__option__txt">option 1</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="select-7181726option-22" data-index="1" data-value="2" role="option" class="select__option" aria-selected="false">
        <span class="select__option__lbl">  
            <span class="select__option__txt">option 2</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="select-7181726option-33" data-index="2" data-value="3" role="option" class="select__option" aria-selected="false">
        <span class="select__option__lbl">  
            <span class="select__option__txt">option 3</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="select-7181726option-44" data-index="3" data-value="4" role="option" class="select__option active" aria-selected="true">
        <span class="select__option__lbl">  
            <span class="select__option__txt">option 4</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="select-7181726option-55" data-index="4" data-value="5" role="option" class="select__option" aria-selected="false">
        <span class="select__option__lbl">  
            <span class="select__option__txt">option 5</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

What can i do to make the screen reader read it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it’s quite complicated to make a custom drop-down menu that’s also accessible, there’s no easy fix. I would suggest reading this post https://inclusive-components.design/menus-menu-buttons/.

Comment: I guess the easiest fix would be to use a `<select>` element, but then you can’t apply custom styles to the drop-down.

Comment: That is not a feasible solution for now, may be a last option. @TedWhitehead

Comment: I just tested using VoiceOver and the raw HTML is read when moving from one option to another. Could you post an example with your JS and CSS included? That may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i found a solution for this, the problem with my code was, it was not changing the value in the input field as we scroll through option. changing the value of input field while as we go through the options makes the screen reader read them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to give your listbox a `tabindex=“0”` and put focus on it to have the functionality you wish.